# How to disable a language while still being able to create content for it

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a website with already 2 languages. I want to add a 3 one, but I obviously don't want it to be accessible until it is finished. If I disable to language, I can't create content in it anymore.

Anyone has a suggestion?

Thank

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the [Hidden Language](https://www.drupal.org/project/hidden_language) module.

> This module allows site admins to hide languages from end-users. As opposed to disabling language content editors still can translate content to that language. It's useful if you don't have entire website translated.

Comment: Wasn't sure since it only had 4 current users and no release version. I figured my "problem" was something common. I'll check it out and get back here with results !

Comment: After trying the module, the "hidden" column did not appear, therefore I had to make my own code.

Answer (score 0):

when testing new items, elements, modules, etc a general rule of thumb:

- only test on a test(development) server - never test new items on a production server

I would suggest something along these lines:

- If you haven't already, set up a test server on a local machine - there are plenty of resources available to do this depending on your OS
- take a backup of the current production site files and DB
- copy those to your test server so you have a mirror to work with
- make all changes to modules, settings, etc - keep track of the changes you make
- test new settings
- when testing shows you have it the way you want, make the changes you recorded earlier to the production site
- BEFORE DEPLOYING ON PRODUCTION SITE: MAKE ANOTHER BACKUP COPY OF PRODUCTION DB AND FILES
- test on the production site imediately, preferrably putting it into maintenance mode so users can't inadvertantly change things or add content that may be lost - if anything is wrong you can restore the site from the most recent backup